# Hibernate Multiple Table Query Performance

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping, query-performance

I have a project which has a dashboard page. within that dashboard page, I have to show :

1. Statistic Charts
2. New information
3. New user suggestions for the admin
4. Number of new messages
5. ETC

Now each of the above info are related to different tables within my database.

I have created different Entities and I'm using hibernate. Suppose **client-A** opens his dashboard, I should execute multiple queries for gathering all the info from all of those entities. Here are the challenges:

1. Since each request runs in one thread at a time within my program, each queries must be finish for the other query to run (it's not simultaneously)
2. We can not create multiple queries at once and map into different entities in hibernate
3. The @Formula annotation can not map whole entity and just map single data type

I was thinking the best approach for having an efficient and fast output is to create one Big Native query and get all data at once with a Single query **BUT** if I'm gonna do this, I have to write native query and map everything by myself which makes the sole of using hibernate faint.

The other approach I'm thinking is to use **executor service** and multi-threading in my application

Now my question is, what is the best approach that I still can use hibernate mapping and issue high performance query ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have put a good amount of effort in writing this post, but at the end, it's just asking for an opinion, which is not suitable for this site.

Comment: @BheshGurung this is not an opinion, I'm asking for best approach implementing a right and appropriate application. This is completely technical, you better read the question again

Comment: Sorry, but when you're saying, "what is the best approach", you are simply asking for an opinion.

Comment: @BheshGurung it's not that. if you say this so, there should not be any design pattern question within this site. they are also best approaches in software development

Comment: There can be design pattern related questions. e.g. you can ask, "How to implement Singleton pattern in Java?". Then five different people will show you five different ways to implement it. Which is ok. But you can also ask, "Which implementation is the best?" Which is not ok because you are just asking for an opinion about why each one thinks his own version is the best. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @BheshGurung when I'm asking how in hibernate I should implement such approach, this means is not off topic. Don't argue with me, I know what I'm doing. When I'm asking which one is right, ExecuterService or Big Query, it's not off topic. When I'm asking how to make use of hibernate for having multiple simultaneously query on the database, it's not off-topic. As I said, I know what I'm doing and you better read the question again

Comment: Is this a web application you're describing with a dashboard?  I'm a bit confused by your statement `"request runs in one thread, so each query must finish before the next can run"`.  The only time I would think you'd want to use an `ExecutorService` would be is if this is some native app you've written; however if this is a web application, is there a reason why you dont have each "widget" send a web request to fetch its content and allow the server architecture to deal with the multi-threaded needs like its designed to support?

Comment: @Naros As you might know in different application servers like "Tomcat" the server creates multi-thread request BUT that is **Per Request** coming from each user! Now suppose "User-A" opens his dashboard page. it is true that **application server** creates him a different thread **by nature** but still that is only **One Single Thread** and queries within your code executes with that single thread. Now I was thinking to create an ExecutorService on that Single Thread to make parrarel **Sub Thread** of the Single thread for having multiple queries into the database simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to stem from the notion that you believe you need to gather all the information for your dashboard in one controller call in order to render a single page.   What you should do is take a step back and try to *componentize* your dashboard.

In other words, what I mean is take advantage of the asynchronous nature of Ajax.

There really is not a reason to use an executor service with today's modern browser tech when the browser can handle initiating multiple web requests asynchronously to render a single web page.

Comment: Actually I knew about this approach but I didn't want to do it because that's a lots of work for each page and I just wanna deliver my project ASAP
Do you have any comment about creating view that can fetch all data in whole from multiple tables and let hibernate fetch those data ?

Comment: what I mean by view is **database view**

Comment: Just create your database view like you normally would and then either (1) create an entity that maps to your view, marking the entity as `@Immutable` given that the data comes from a view and you shouldn't try to change it via the application or (2) use a Tuple-based query to fetch the data from the view.  There's plenty of information about this already on Stack Overflow or the net.

Comment: thanks Naros, I already master of this with Hibernate! Actually I went ahead with componentized solution together with JQuery asynchronous request and I think this is the most systematic solution, and it's working very fine for me